# Here Maps - Center map to show all markers

Tags: maps, centering, here-api

im trying to display a clustered map and i want to center the map according to the displayed clusters. is it possible?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can add your cluster to a group and then set the bounding box of the map same as that of the group. Something done like in the following example

https://developer.here.com/documentation/examples/maps-js/markers/zoom-to-set-of-markers